# Scala Play Convert List of List into Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to convert a list of lists into Json. So far I am able to convert the first item into an Json but how do it do it for the entire list?

Currently I have the following:

```
  def jsonAll = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    val list = Performances.listAll

    val w = Json.obj(
      "items" -> Json.arr(
        Json.obj("performance" -> list(0)._1),
        Json.obj("location" -> list(0)._2),
        Json.obj("user" -> list(0)._3)
      )
    )

    Ok(Json.toJson(w))
  }
```

The 'list' is defined as:

```
  def listAll: List[(Performance, Location, DBUser)] = {
    ...
  }
```

Note: You also have to define the format for the individual objects.

```
  implicit val performanceFormat = Json.format[Performance]
  implicit val locationFormat = Json.format[Location]
  implicit val userFormat = Json.format[DBUser]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an own type for Performances and just using `Json.toJson`?

```
case class Performance(performance: String, location: String, user: String)

implicit val performancesWrites = new Writes[Performance] {
  def writes(p: Performance) = Json.obj(
    "performance" -> p.performance,
    "location" -> p.location,
    "user" -> p.user
  )
}

val list = List(("hi", "there", "buddy"), ("meep", "eleven", "foobar"))
val performances = list.map((Performance.apply _) tupled)    
val resultingJson = Json.toJson(performances)

// Yields: [{"performance":"hi","location":"there","user":"buddy"},{"performance":"meep","location":"eleven","user":"foobar"}]
```

Comment: Hey thanks let me try this out. The only reason why this might not work is because for me Location, Performance and User are their own object and it seems like you are making a Writes[Performance] rather than a Writes[List[(Performance, Location, DBUser)]]

Comment: Just make a Writes[Location], Writes[Performance] and Writes[User] just like I did to tell Play how to write these types to Json.

Play.json already knows how to write Lists, so the only missing thing is to tell it how to write Performances.

Answer (score 0):

So more research and diving further into the weird world of Scala(I come from Java) I found the solution:

```
  def jsonAll = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    val list = Performances.listAll

    val re = list.map(
      iter =>
        Json.obj(
          "performance" -> iter._1,
          "location" -> iter._2,
          "user" -> iter._3
        )
    )

    Ok(Json.toJson(re))
  }
```

Simple once you know the syntax :|

Comment: This isn't the idiomatic solution—see the answer from phdoerlfler.